# Interactive ggplot in Markdown

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, r-markdown

The examples on http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html indicate that `renderPlot` itself renders the plot to the markdown. How can we get our markdown to allow interactions such as clicks, brushes, etc. which are declared as part of the subsequent `plotOutput` step?

Interactivity examples with `plotOutput` in `shiny` here - http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html.

Code snippet -

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}

output[['Plot1']] = renderPlot(

   ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = qsec))

) 

renderPlot(

   ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = wt))

)


print("renderPlot above. plotOutput below (which doesn't get rendered).")

renderUI({
   plotOutput(
      'Plot1',
      brush = brushOpts(
         id = 'Brush1'
      ),
      dblclick = dblclickOpts(id = 'DblClick1'),
      click = 'Click1',
      height = "100%"

   )
})

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the parameter `height` in `plotOutput` with percents. We can find in the documentation `?shiny::plotOutput`:

> Note that, for height, using "auto" or "100%" generally will not work as expected, because of how height is computed with HTML/CSS.

If you remove `height = 100%`, which is in this case redundant, the plot will be rendered. If you want to change the height of the output you can use pixels instead of percents.

Then you can access values via `input$Click1`, `input$DblClick1` and `input$Brush1` and pass them to render* functions.

---

**Example:**

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "Unnamed_User"
date: "24 Sep 2016"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
```

### Normal plot

```{r, echo = FALSE} 
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = wt))
``` 


### Interactive plot

```{r, echo = FALSE}
renderUI({
   plotOutput(
      'Plot1',
      brush = brushOpts(
         id = 'Brush1'
      ),
      dblclick = dblclickOpts(id = 'DblClick1'),
      click = 'Click1'
   )
})

output[['Plot1']] <- renderPlot({ 
   ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = qsec))
})
```

### Clicked point

```{r, echo = FALSE}
renderPrint({ 
  cat(" x:", input$Click1$x, 
      "\n",
       "y:", input$Click1$y)
})
```
````